# How to catch exception thrown from @Formula annotation in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I bump into a scenario using `@Formula` annotation from Hibernate in my `jsf` application. 
One of my Entity property used to get value from a associated Entity column marked using `@Formula` annotation, the query is simple select from that column, sometimes the value is `null` and i get `EntityNotFoundException` when iterating to my Entity. How am i going to catch this error and or maybe suppress this error so that i won't get error on my page.

How am i going to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post code snippet where annotation is used? would be easier to help!

Comment: You can't catch that exception. Usually, the way to avoid the exception is to change the query, so if one of the parameters is null, the query will return a default value (such as 0). Also, you **DON'T** want to catch the exception, as the EntityManager becomes invalid after any error.

Comment: What happens if there is no match found in the Database. What value would it return? Thanks. :)